# Sci-fi book, blue critters than only some people can see, kids fight the critters as they feed off energy and are a threat

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I can't really remember how long ago it was, but I think the book was marketed towards children/teens.  All I remember is the basic premise of the story.

Some story about these unusual little blue electric critters that only certain people could see, and these kids took it upon themselves to go about destroying them since they fed off energy or something like that.  Not sure whether they fed off people or off electricity... or both maybe?  I think the dominant method of destroying them was an electric baton that was taken from law enforcement.  I wanna call them buzz batons, but that's probably thanks to *Artemis Fowl*.

Comment: Sounds almost... smurfy.

Comment: @Omegacron - I smurf an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[*The Supernaturalist*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Supernaturalist) (2004) by Eoin Colfer.

> "In the not-too-distant future, in a place called Satellite City,
> thirteen-year-old Cosmo Hill is unfortunate enough to come into the
> world unwanted by his parents. And so, as are all orphaned boys his
> age, Cosmo is dipped in a vaccine vat and sent to the Clarissa Frayne
> Institute for Parentally Challenged Boys-freight class. At Clarissa
> Frayne, the orphans, called "no-sponsors," are put to work by the
> state, testing dangerous products that never should be allowed near
> human beings. By the time the no-sponsors are sent to their cardboard
> utility pipes, given their nightly meal pack, and finally fall asleep,
> they are often covered in burns, bruises, or sores from the work of
> the day. Cosmo Hill knows that he must escape, even though he has no
> idea what might be waiting for him on the outside. He plans for the
> moment when he can make a break. When that moment finally comes, he
> nearly dies while escaping. But he is rescued by a gang of
> "Supernaturalists," a motley crew of kids who all have a special
> psychic ability-one that Cosmo is about to learn he has as well. They
> "see" supernatural Parasites-tiny, translucent creatures who feed on
> the life force of humans.
>
> - <sub><sup>[B&N Review](https://www.unc.edu/%7Eloendorf/super.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: Thankyou, this is definitely the book I was looking for!  Also, no wonder buzz batons came to mind...  (same author afterall lol).