# Novel: kid shoots a rocket down the barrel of a tank!

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

So i read this book in mid to late 2000s.
Future dystpoian setting

I remember the main characters were at least a boy and a girl. The boy at least, idk if the girl was aswell, was owned by a pharmacutical corporation and was used as a test subject. Specifically i remember him saying that his legs burned and i think he was on a treadmill all day so possible deoderant test kinda thing happening.

He slept in a big room with the other children and slept in a cot matrix that was very tall so like 10 cots connected to poles maybe.

He escapes.

The girl is a master mechanic for street racing gang, shes like 13 and a badass. The gang has glowing body modifications and cyborg muscle mods. Modding themselves as much as there cars.

The are escaping from or fighting the government and he shoots an rpg down the barrel of a tank at the split second the safety guard opens to fire a round at him and destroys the tank.

Still gets captured.

Thats all i remember, please help.

Comment: Sounds like the Supernaturalist by Eoin Colfer. I don't think I own a copy any more though.

Comment: I just looked it up and thats my book! Double win that its by eoin colfer!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely *[The Supernaturalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Supernaturalist)* by Eoin Colfer.

> "In the not-too-distant future, in a place called Satellite City,
>   thirteen-year-old Cosmo Hill is unfortunate enough to come into the
>   world unwanted by his parents. And so, as are all orphaned boys his
>   age, Cosmo is dipped in a vaccine vat and sent to the Clarissa Frayne
>   Institute for Parentally Challenged Boys-freight class. At Clarissa
>   Frayne, the orphans, called "no-sponsors," are put to work by the
>   state, testing dangerous products that never should be allowed near
>   human beings. By the time the no-sponsors are sent to their cardboard
>   utility pipes, given their nightly meal pack, and finally fall asleep,
>   they are often covered in burns, bruises, or sores from the work of
>   the day. Cosmo Hill knows that he must escape, even though he has no
>   idea what might be waiting for him on the outside. He plans for the
>   moment when he can make a break. When that moment finally comes, he
>   nearly dies while escaping. But he is rescued by a gang of
>   "Supernaturalists," a motley crew of kids who all have a special
>   psychic ability-one that Cosmo is about to learn he has as well. They
>   "see" supernatural Parasites-tiny, translucent creatures who feed on
>   the life force of humans. - <sub><sup>[B&N Review](http://www.unc.edu/~loendorf/super.htm)</sup></sub>

(Copied from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/77489/41144))

All of the other elements you mention are present in the book. You may recall that one of the drag drivers incorporated LED lights on his chest.

The scene with the rocket down the barrel of a tank that you recall is when (and this is from memory, I don't have my copy of the book with me at the moment) was when one of the characters takes a non-lethal weapon from a paralegal (in the scene described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Supernaturalist), when the Myishi paralegals come to recover the prototype car), and fires the Saran-wrap type net down the barrel of a tank's water cannon, preventing it from shooting a mass of people at an illegal drag race. He is captured anyway at the end of that scene.

(This was also mentioned by [DaaaahWhoosh](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/46611/daaaahwhoosh) in the [comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160485/novel-kid-shoots-a-rocket-down-the-barrel-of-a-tank/160494#comment423015_160485))

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice that the OP [confirmed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160485/novel-kid-shoots-a-rocket-down-the-barrel-of-a-tank/160494#comment423017_160485) that this was the book. If this answer helped you, Christopher, consider marking it as the accepted answer.